# Can I plot points in ArcGIS if I only have distances from a set coordinate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, gps, distance

I understand there is a way to plot lat,long data from a table (dbf) in ArcMap, but is there any way to plot x,y data if you only have distances away from a set coordinate instead of lat, long?

To clarify and specify my task: Square plots were set up and a GPS coordinate was recorded for each corner. Then the distances (m) from the north corner were recorded in the x and y direction for every tree in the plot. I was hoping to plot these trees in ArcMap, but don't want to plot each tree individually by way of creating a shapefile and adding each feature in (too many trees!!).So, I was wondering if there was any way to upload all these points with one or a few steps?  I already have a .csv file with all of the tree numbers/attributes and their respective x and y distances away from the corners.

Comment: What type of method are you looking for? Would you like to use `arcpy` or rather not? Are your corner coordinates lat / long in a global projection (using angular units) or in a projected coordinate system using metres? If the latter ist the case, I'd simply manipulate the coordinates in Excel (i.e. corner_X + distance_X1 / corner_Y + distance_Y1) to obtain coordinates for every tree. Of course you could do the same using an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`.